# Type inference for class instances as method arguments

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

I'm trying to build a FlowBuilder that basically just puts steps in a stack.
The steps (or step classes) all extend an abstract class

```
abstract class AbstractFlowBuilderStep<
    TType extends string,
    TRunParameters extends Record<string, any>,
    TRunReturnValue
> {
  public constructor(public readonly type: TType) {}
  public abstract run(parameters: TRunParameters): TRunReturnValue;
}
```

For example, one such step class is:

```
class FunctionFlowBuilderStep<
    TRunParameters extends Record<string, any>,
    TFunctionReturnValue
> extends AbstractFlowBuilderStep<'function', TRunParameters, TFunctionReturnValue> {
  public constructor(public readonly func: (parameters: TRunParameters) => TFunctionReturnValue) {
    super('function');
  }
  public run(parameters: TRunParameters) {
    return this.func(parameters);
  }
}
```

Also I have some helping interfaces:

```
interface FlowBuilderStepWithLabel<
    TLabel extends string = string,
    TStep extends AbstractFlowBuilderStep<string, any, any> = AbstractFlowBuilderStep<string, any, any>
> {
  label: TLabel;
  step: TStep;
};

interface FlowBuilderStepRunParameters<
    TFlowConfiguration extends Record<string, any> = any,
> {
  flowConfiguration: TFlowConfiguration;
};
```

Now here is the FlowBuilder itself:

```
class FlowBuilder<
    TConfiguration extends Record<string, any>,
    TStepsWithLabels extends readonly FlowBuilderStepWithLabel<
      string,
      AbstractFlowBuilderStep<string,
        FlowBuilderStepRunParameters<TConfiguration>,
        any
      >
    >[]
> {
  public readonly configuration: TConfiguration;
  public readonly stepsWithLabels: TStepsWithLabels;

  public constructor(configuration: TConfiguration, ...stepsWithLabels: TStepsWithLabels) {
    this.configuration = configuration;
    this.stepsWithLabels = stepsWithLabels;
  }

  public addStep<
      TLabel extends string,
      TStep extends AbstractFlowBuilderStep< // It works if I drop this generic and replace TStep below by the extends-part. 
        string,
        FlowBuilderStepRunParameters<TConfiguration>,
        any
      >
  >(label: TLabel, step: TStep): FlowBuilder<TConfiguration, readonly [...TStepsWithLabels, FlowBuilderStepWithLabel<TLabel, TStep>]> {
    return new FlowBuilder(
      this.configuration,
      ...this.stepsWithLabels,
      {label: label, step: step}
    );
  }
}
```

But when I test this as follows:

```
const flowBuilder = new FlowBuilder({abc: 123})
  .addStep('firstStep', new FunctionFlowBuilderStep((params) => 'xyz'));
// params is of type Record<string, any> but should be {flowConfiguration: {abc: number}}.
```

the type of `params` is not inferred like I want (as `{abc: number}`). Instead, it is `Record<string, any>`, despite I explicitly use `FlowBuilderStepRunParameters<TConfiguration>` in the `extends` part of `TStep`!

Interestingly, it would work when I do not use `TStep` at all but just let the param `step` be of the type that `TStep` extends. However, I would like to keep `TStep` as generic, also because otherwise the information seems to be lost which class the step belongs to (here, for instance, `FunctionFlowBuilderStep`).

Comment: I don't see a way to do this either. In general TS cannot infer arbitrary generic type arguments and contextual function parameter types at the same time; see [ms/TS#47599](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599). Support for specific instances has been steadily improving, but it will probably always be a limitation. When all else fails you can manually specify a generic type argument or manually annotate a function param, and that's the best I can find here. *Maybe* there's something better but I can't wade though `NounVerberNounVerbNouns` and `TVerberNounNoun` anymore to find it.